# org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Invalid message length sa00

Tags: java, logging, jpos

Hie. I am encountering a bug that I dont really understand. So I have succesfully made a connection between my client which is being hosted by a web server and my sever program. But after the logger on the server side prints the last reply message, it is printing this extra segment which is an exception and i cant figure out why. Help?

```html
 <field id="999" value="REPLY TO CLIENT"/>
    </isomsg>
  </send>
</log>
<log realm="server-channel-logger/127.0.0.1:56948" at="2018-01-05T12:42:56.467" lifespan="9ms">
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="incoming">
      <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87APackager -->
      <field id="0" value="F204"/>
      <field id="2" value=""/>
      <field id="3" value="0000F8"/>
      <field id="4" value="0000194000-1"/>
      <field id="43" value="234-5678-9909003000000000005674010214115"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
<log realm="server-channel-logger/127.0.0.1:56948" at="2018-01-05T12:42:56.501" lifespan="7ms">
  <send>
    <isomsg direction="outgoing">
      <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87APackager -->
      <field id="0" value="0110"/>
      <field id="2" value=""/>
      <field id="3" value="0000F8"/>
      <field id="4" value="0000194000-1"/>
      <field id="39" value="00"/>
      <field id="43" value="234-5678-9909003000000000005674010214115"/>
      <field id="999" value="REPLY TO CLIENT"/>
    </isomsg>
  </send>
</log>
<log realm="server-channel-logger/127.0.0.1:56948" at="2018-01-05T12:42:56.517" lifespan="1ms">
  <receive>
    <iso-exception>
      Invalid message length sa00
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Invalid message length sa00
 at org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel.getMessageLength(ASCIIChannel.java:118)
 at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:701)
 at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:344)
 at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:76)
    </iso-exception>
  </receive>
</log>
<log realm="server-logger.session/127.0.0.1:56948" at="2018-01-05T12:42:56.540">
  <session-error>
    <iso-exception>
      Invalid message length sa00
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Invalid message length sa00
 at org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel.getMessageLength(ASCIIChannel.java:118)
 at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:701)
 at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:344)
 at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:76)
    </iso-exception>
  </session-error>
</log>
<log realm="server-logger.session/127.0.0.1:56948" at="2018-01-05T12:42:56.603">
  <session-end/>
</log>
```

Comment: Can you share how you are trying to connect from your web server to your server program? Please add it to your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to *speak* ISO-8583 against an HTTP server, there's no way this is going to work.

Comment: Really? How do I fix it? Because I need to open the channel from a web container

Comment: You can certainly open the channel from your web container. Make sure the spec matches your ISO-8583 server side. If you choose to use Q2 from jPOS-EE, you can easily use jPOS-EE Jetty Module for your web server needs, and you have all the Q2 ISO-8583 support available for you. See http://jpos.org/doc/jPOS-EE.pdf

Comment: thanks, its working great now. I decided to switch to Q2